# How to change the fileupload dialog files view?

Tags: nautilus, icons, filemanager, dialog, upload

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I noticed that, when I'm using the browser and want to upload a file, I see something like this:

[image: example from the internet - list-view]

I wanted to know if I could change the view of these files, instead of a list-view (as the image 1), I wanted a icon view, like this:

[image: example from the internet - icon view]

P.S: I thought the problem was the "nautilus", so I changed my file manager to the "nemo" but the problem continued the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience we cannot change the view when we want to upload a file. We only can change the view when we are using the file manager in the option "Preferences"